# How to list the email addresses of people in Contacts.app (Address Book.app)

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

I am looking for a way in bash to transfer the contents of the file located in

```
~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb
```

to a textual format. I believe it is an SQL file, but I am not quite sure as I have never seen the .abcddb extension before. Is this even possible in the shell?

Comment: What app are you talking about? 'cause it sure ain't a bash built-in...

Comment: This is not a clear question

Comment: Your contacts are in a SQLite database. You could do it all from the shell, without using AppleScript.

Comment: I had tried opening it in SQLite Database Browser but nothing was visible. ? @Mark

Comment: General remark: I don't understand why people have downvoted this question. If you know something about AppleScript and you know what Address Book is, then you understand that this is a valid question. If you don't know about AppleScript and Address Book, then you're not qualified to vote.

Comment: @54m The SQLite file should be at ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/. Check out that directory and find the correct file name. Be careful!

Comment: Thanks a ton Mark! I absolutely agree with you on the "General remark". I was very confused as to why people were down voting as well...anyways, thanks again for your repsonse it helped greatly! @Mark

Comment: I just had a look in that directory on my own Mac, this morning. Those acdddb files should be database files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to linefeed' -e 'tell application "Contacts" to (value of email 1 of people) as text'`

To get a list of the email addresses, first names, and last names, run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
set out to ""
tell application "Contacts" to repeat with p in people
    if emails of p is {} then
        set e to ""
    else
        set e to value of email 1 of p
    end if
    set out to out & e & ";" & first name of p & ";" & last name of p & linefeed
end repeat
out
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for any confusion with the question